# Updating Joomla Module Source Doesnt reflect changes

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions, joomla1.7, joomla2.5

I am trying to modify the source code of Joomla module but I don't see the changes on the UI. I tried clearing the browse cache and Joomla cache as well from the admin panel but this didn't work as well. Anyone has any idea about this why the changes are not reflecting on the UI ?

Comment: Have you made sure you're editing the correct file in the correct location? Also try force refreshing using CTRL + F5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I suspect you are doing changes in wrong location. And that is because some templates have their own implementation of HTML/PHP for certain modules. Like most of the templates have html for login modules in them. You should look into the template folder and the one that is active on your site.

The module that you are editing will be under /modules/mod_login

but actually it wont be executed if you have "mod_login" defined in your template which should be somewhere like this:
 /templates/**|your active template folder|**/html/mod_login

So that is the location where your actual module HTML implementation is found. Try editing that file if it exists there.

If you dont find that file/folder then there must be something wrong with your Joomla 2.5 setup or with that module in particular.

Let me know if you need further assistance. (I am actually a professional Joomla! support provider)